# Как передать из контроллера в JavaScript переменную (дату)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

Дано:

Вот такой вот пример таймера

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown

Задача передать в скрипт свою дату.

Есть:
Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/passing/{id}")
public String startPassing(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer qId, Model model) {

    Test test = this.testService.getFullTestById(id);
    Date date = resService.addResult(test, userService.findByUsername(securityService.getName()));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d y H:m:s ZZZ");
    String dateString = formatter.format(date);
    model.addAttribute("ourDate", dateString);

    return "testPassing";
}
```

Попытка в jsp прописать строку:
    var countDownDate = new Date("${ourDate}").getTime();

Что не дает никакого ровным счетом результата. Пробовал убирать кавычки. Пробовал прописать все в стиле ${ourDate.getTime()}. Либо не работает либо вообще ломается

=====================================
UPD

Вот весь код метода контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/passing/{id}")
public String startPassing(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer qId, Model model) {

    Test test = this.testService.getFullTestById(id);
    Date date = resService.addResult(test, userService.findByUsername(securityService.getName()));
    /*
     * model.addAttribute("passingTest", test); model.addAttribute("questionSize",
     * test.getQuestions().size()); System.out.println(test.getQuestions().size());
     */
    model.addAttribute("passingTest", test);
    int pageSize = test.getQuestions().size();
    List<Question> questions = test.getQuestions();
    model.addAttribute("questionSize", test.getQuestions().size());
    // model.addAttribute("time", arg1)
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d y H:m:s ZZZ");
    String dateString = formatter.format(date);
    model.addAttribute("ourDate", dateString);

    if (qId == null || qId < 1 || qId > pageSize) {
        qId = 1;
        model.addAttribute("qId", qId);
        model.addAttribute("question", questions.get(qId));

    } else if (qId <= pageSize) {
        model.addAttribute("qId", qId);
        model.addAttribute("question", questions.get(qId - 1));
    }

    return "testPassing";
}
```

testPassing.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">
<%-- 
<link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet"> --%>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<style>
p {
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
}
</style>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
                    <li><c:url var="formPerson" value="/personalOffice" /> <a
                        href="${formPerson}">Personal Office</a></li>
                </c:if>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
                        <li><c:url var="logout" value="/logout" /> <a
                            href="${logout}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
                                logout</a></li>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <li><c:url var="formLoginUrl" value="/login" /> <a
                            href="${formLoginUrl}"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                        <li><c:url var="formRegistrationUrl" value="/registration" />
                            <a href="${formRegistrationUrl}"> <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> Registration
                        </a></li>

                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <li><a href="?lang=ru" class="btn">ru</a></li>
                <li><a href="?lang=ua" class="btn">ua</a></li>
                <li><a href="?lang=en" class="btn">en</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("${ourDate}").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
                / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60))
                / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours
                + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
<div id="pagination">

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="80"><spring:message code="question.text" /></th>
                <th width="80">${question.text}</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach items="${question.answers}" var="answer">
            <tr>
                <td>${answer.id}</td>
                <td>${answer.answer}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

    <c:url value="/passing/${passingTest.id}" var="prev">
        <c:param name="qId" value="${qId-1}" />
    </c:url>
    <c:if test="${qId > 1}">
        <a href="<c:out value="${prev}" />" class="pn prev">Prev</a>
    </c:if>

    <c:forEach begin="1" end="${questionSize}" step="1" varStatus="i">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${qId == i.index}">
                <span>${i.index}</span>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:url value="/passing/${passingTest.id}" var="url">
                    <c:param name="qId" value="${i.index}" />
                </c:url>
                <a href='<c:out value="${url}" />'>${i.index}</a>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:url value="/passing/${passingTest.id}" var="next">
        <c:param name="qId" value="${qId + 1}" />
    </c:url>
    <c:if test="${qId + 1 <= questionSize}">
        <a href='<c:out value="${next}" />' class="pn next">Next</a>
    </c:if>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Отображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если посмотреть на код страницы в браузере, то там какое значение подставляется?

Comment: Если писать "var countDownDate = new Date("${Date}").getTime();" то отобразится "NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs"
Если "var countDownDate = new Date(${Date}).getTime();"
то в коде появляется "var countDownDate = new Date(Пн июл 31 2017 21:0:38 +0300).getTime();"

Comment: у вас же в вопросе переменная по другому называется.

Comment: Да , для наглядности я поменял название)

Comment: не надо ничего менять. покажите кусок jsp и кусок результата. добавьте все прямо в вопрос в виде кода.

Comment: Готово , добавил весь код

Comment: добавьте исходный кода страницы с результатом.

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо Mikhail Vaysman за наведение меня на мысль о просмотре исходного кода страницы!
Дело было в том что я присылал дату с кривой кодировкой.
Прописано было "new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d y H:m:s ZZZ");"
А надо было "new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);"